# Getting string from project Resources in VS c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have defined some strings within the Rersources tab in Project Properties.

The way I try to get such values is:

```
rm = new ResourceManager("items", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
rm.GetString("DBO_LISTA_URLS_TEST");
```

The question is that I do not know what's 'items' and where to get it from.

What's the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parameter of `ResourceManager` constructor is a full namespace of your resource file. I've added two resource files (fisrt from project properties window and second by 'Add new item'):

[image: project with resources]

Now I can get strings from them:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var projResource = new ResourceManager("ResourcesDemo.Properties.Resources", assembly);
var customResource = new ResourceManager("ResourcesDemo.Custom", assembly);

Console.WriteLine(projResource.GetString("DBO_LISTA_URLS_TEST"));
Console.WriteLine(customResource.GetString("CUSTOM_RESOURCE"));
```